# MaxListenersExceededWarning caused by Promise.All in a loop

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm running into a problem with `Promise.All` and not sure how to work around it. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

I have the following code structure

```
for (const site of sites) {
    promiseFunction(url);
}
async function asyncFunction(url) {
    const promiseVar = await Promise.all([
        functionName(),
    ]);
}
```

but it's generating the following error

```
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

How can I force each loop iteration to complete before performing the next, or is there a way of alleviating this issue that I'm not aware of?

Comment: that promise.all is redundant.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly do you want to achieve? If you want to await the execution of the function inside the loop - wrap the `for` inside an `async` function and use `await asyncFunction(url)` inside the `for` cycle. However, this also means that the promises won't be fired at the same time (which you should strive for) thus affecting your resolve times as you're awaiting the completion of every single one before firing the request for the next.

Comment: @zhulien - you provided the answer I was looking for! Adding your suggestions has resolved the issue I was running into, so, if you'd like to add it as an answer, I'll accept it and you can benefit from the points? Thank you so much for your time <3